# Puma is not working with nginx in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ssl, nginx, puma

I am using this command manually

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

My server is working fine. I'm able to access the url but when i bind the socket with nginx, I'm unable to access the server.

My nginx configuration is

```
upstream puma_agarscents { 
  server unix:/var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name x.x.x.x; # change to match your URL
  root /var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/current/public;

  listen 443 ssl;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://puma_agarscents;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Getting the below error

> 2015/05/14 05:34:31 [error] 6802#0: *79 connect() to
>   unix:/var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed
>   (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream,
>   client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.x.x, request: "GET
>   /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/favicon.ico",
>   host: "x.x.x.x"

Comment: Check socket permissions.

Comment: srwxrwxrwx   this is permission for sockets

Comment: And permissions for all parent directories? `namei -l /var/www/rails_apps/agarcents/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock`

Comment: every parent directory has the same permissions.

Comment: Well, that it's probably problem with selinux. I'm not good with it, but you could check http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/selinux+nginx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selinux+nginx

Comment: @AlexeyTen can you please describe the problem so that i could apply direct patch/solutions

Comment: Any update on this issue?